# Call Typehead function on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

Hello I am using [typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/) jquery library.

I want to run the function in keyup but it is now working.

**JQuery code :**

```
$.typeahead({
    input: '.js-typeahead-car_v1',
    minLength: 1,
    maxItem: 0,
    order: "asc",
    hint: true,

    source: {
        searchkey: {
            url: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/search",
                data: {
                    myKey: "muvalue"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    callback: {
        onClick: function (node, a, item, event) {
            $("#topsearchbtn").trigger( "click" );
        },
    }
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" name="term" class="form-control input-sm js-typeahead-car_v1"
       maxlength="64" placeholder="Search Entire store here..." id="tags" autocomplete='off' />
```

How can I call `$.typeahead({})` on keyup?

Right now it is sending request 1st time key up not every time.

Answer (score 1):

Typeahead is meant to be binded like this:

```
$("#tags").typeahead({
    // Arguments
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/cnmfl/2/).

Maybe something is wrong somewhere else in your typeahead query.

Comment: Thanks but same the search suggestion not coming.

Comment: The function is triggered this way, I have zero doubt about that. In your case, maybe the object you pass in the typeahead method is wrong.

Comment: @DeepParekh could you try with the minimum amount of arguments in the typeahead function to make sure things go right.

Comment: If i alert inside on keyup the alert coming but it is not coming inside $.typehead({}). DO YOU HAVE ANY IDEA ??

Comment: @DeepParekh try to write a JSFiddle so that we can see the thing as a whole

Comment: HI i tried your code but i am getting error "custom.js:425 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

Comment: The selector couldn't find the HTML elements. Make sure you wrote the ID right

Comment: Also, I can see that you constantly write typehead, it's type**a**head

Comment: Also, did you include the jQuery file?

Comment: Any news about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#tags', function() {
    $.typeahead({
       // your code
    });
}
```

or

```
$('#tags').on('keyup', function() {
    $.typeahead({
     // your code
    });
}
```